# Windows phone 8.1 deploy erro: DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8-1

Ao fazer o deploy ou debug do projeto aparece este erro `DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -1988945906`.
Ele compila tudo certo, porém, quando vai para instalar no celular aparece o erro.
No emulador funciona normalmente.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro é causado pelo motivo do serviço `IpOverUsbSvc` estar parado.

> Vá no gerenciador de tarefas >Aba serviços > procure pelo serviço
>   IpOverUsbSvc

Clique com o botão direito do mouse e iniciar serviço.

Comment: Excelente resposta, rápida, direta e explicativa ao mesmo tempo! +1